# Como recuperar um idUsuario(user_id) de uma models de um idAnuncio(ad_id) pelas routes do Discounts(Desconto)? API REST

Tags: node.js, api, sqlite, express.js

Preciso fazer uma query para recuperar descontos de um Usuario(idUsuario = user_id) pelas routes da models Desconto, porém, desconto só está relacionado a um idAnuncio(ad_id), então é tipo recuperar um id através de outro id...

A arquitetura da API segue o padrão MVR e models e routes estão na estrutura do Express.

Banco de dados é o sqlite.

Segue a estrutura das models:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o get de um Desconto, que preciso fazer pelo idUsuario(user_id):

```
module.exports = app => {

const Discount = app.db.models.Discount;

//rota para todos descontos somente de um usuario/fornecedor 
app.route("/discounts/provider/:ad_id")
    .get((req, res) => {
        Discount.findAll({ where: req.params })
            .then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    res.json(result);
                } else {
                    res.sendStatus(404);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                res.status(412).json({ msg: error.message });
            });
    })
}
```

Segue o arquivo do banco de dados db.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let db = null;

module.exports = app => {
if (!db) {
    const config = app.libs.config;
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config.params
    );
    db = {
        sequelize,
        Sequelize,
        models: {}
    };
    const dir = path.join(__dirname, "models");
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
        const modelDir = path.join(dir, file);
        const model = sequelize.import(modelDir);
        db.models[model.name] = model;
    });
    Object.keys(db.models).forEach(key => {
        db.models[key].associate(db.models);
    });
}
    return db;
};
```

Comment: Que biblioteca está usando para manipular o banco? O que é a variável `Ads`?

Comment: Estou usando o sequelize para manipular o banco e Ads esta errado, na verdade é const Discount = app.db.models.Discount;